# Strange Linq Cast Exception

Tags: linq-to-sql, guid, .net

I'm getting a very strange Cast Exception. The exception occurres very rare.

This is the code:

```
    protected Guid GetWebsiteLanguage(Guid websiteId, int languageId)
    {
        Guid websiteLanguagesId = Guid.Empty;
        var websites = from item in DataContext.WebsiteLanguages
                       where item.WebsiteId == websiteId && item.LanguageId == languageId
                       select item.Id;

        if (websites.Count() != 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong channel parameters.");

        try
        {
            websiteLanguagesId = websites.First();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = websites.First() == null ? "websites.First() is null" : string.Concat("Invalid Guid ", websites.First().ToString());
            throw new Exception(string.Concat(ex.Message, " - Log: ", errorMessage, " - Variables: websiteId = ", websiteId.ToString(), " languageId = ", languageId));
        }

        return websiteLanguagesId;
    }
```

The exception I get is this:

**Specified cast is not valid**. - Log:

Invalid Guid ef058612-37db-4b02-aa13-5a528819a5e0

Variables: 
websiteId = db725f45-70fa-4fd0-b344-55bbf17a5c15

languageId = 2057

This is the output of the exception of the catch. As you can see we have a GUID but still he is giving a cast exception...

And sometimes its goes wrong on the Count() of this function. Then this is the stacktrace:

System.Data.Linq.IExecuteResult Execute(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, QueryInfo, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.IObjectReaderFactory, System.Object[], System.Object[], System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ICompiledSubQuery[], System.Object)STACKTRACE:    at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at GetWebsiteLanguage(Guid websiteId, Int32 languageId)

And when this occures the only solution is to do an iis app pool recycle and it is working again.

Any ideas?

This is how I handle my datacontext

```
    public MyDataContext DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            //Changed this to make this testable with unit tests
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(DataContextKey))
                    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(DataContextKey, new MyDataContext(ConnectionString));
                return (MyDataContext)HttpContext.Current.Items[DataContextKey];
            }
            else
            {
                //When context is not available
                if (context == null)
                    context = new MyDataContext(ConnectionString);
                return context;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure what is causing the problem. But I understand you anyway alwas can have only one result? So have you considered not use Count at all. Also your First() in the latter part of the code cannot be null I think.

(If you can have more than one result, use FirstOrDefault instead)

So why not refactor into using SingleOrDefault().:

```
var websites = (from item in DataContext.WebsiteLanguages 
                   where item.WebsiteId == websiteId && item.LanguageId == languageId 
                   select item.Id).SingleOrDefault();
```

and continue with

```
if (websites == null) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong channel parameters.");
```

Comment: I don't know if this solves the problem... Because the exceptions occures sometimes on the count, but another time on the websites.First(); expression.. And if it goes wrong on the First() expression its very strange it has a value in the exception. (as shown in the example)

Comment: And is it reproducable: in other words after the app pool recycle trying the same Guid DOES work or is it consistent in not working?

Comment: And you are right that it might not solve your problem (although you will probably get different sql generated) in that case. But refactoring like this will still improve your performance

Comment: After the app pool recycle the same GUID is working. And after a period of time (sometimes a few months, sometimes weeks) the same problem is reorcurring again.

Comment: How do you handle your datacontext?

Comment: I've added my question with the datacontext

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the `Server Data Type` property to `uniqueidentifier` in my DBML.